# Theoretical Physics is close to launch

Tags: discussion

The [Theoretical Physics SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics?referrer=5_bBucz7A70DvVVb-6SmDQ2) is now rather close to launch, having a good number of participants committed. But, its *commitment score* is rather low, in part because people committed over a long period of time.

**How to help it be launched?**

- if you committed, please refresh your commitment: uncommit then re-commit
- if you didn't commit, please consider it

**2011-09-05 Edit:** thanks everyone, the commitment score is now much higher (gone from 76% to 90%), and we have a larger number of committers. We're gonna make it!

[image: Committers timeline]

Comment: did uncommit and commit. Whats the point, is this a SE system hack do deceive for commiters than there actually are? Would be much easier to start theophysics with a biology and chemistry site already running. Funnily this seems even more tricky........

Comment: @Werner It's not a hack - we decay commitments over time because if you commit to something but several months pass by, then we cannot tell that you're still as active a commitment as you were at the start. Refreshing your commitment is simply a method of saying "Yeah, I'm still here, I still want this site to work out!"

Comment: @grace thx. vs. your voting system area51 is really a rocket science ;)

Comment: Yay, I made 1 additional percent :) @Grace why not offer a "refresh my commitment please" button then? I didn't know about this...

Comment: **100%** Not all we need is a good [subdomain name](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/2814/what-should-the-theoretical-physics-sub-domain-be)