# Theoretical Physics SE - a place for research-level questions

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Just recently, [Theoretical Physics - Stack Exchange](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/) has entered the open beta phase. It is a research-level question site, so we aim at questions that cannot be answered by a standard textbook. We encourage users to, for the most part, ask question directly related to their scientific work. Mathematical, numerical and experimental questions are welcome, as long they are related to theoretical physics (in motivation or used tools).

Interested? Join now!

The idea of TP.SE is to reduplicate the success of [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/), where leading edge questions can be asked... and are often answered. We want to create two-level model, to have relation of [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)/[TP.SE](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/) as there is currently with [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)/[MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).

The idea was widely discussed (also on this meta site), see:

- [Where should research-level questions go? Theoretical Physics SE or Physics Research SE?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/where-should-research-level-questions-go-theoretical-physics-se-or-physics-resea)
- [Theoretical Physics is close to launch](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/884/theoretical-physics-is-close-to-launch)
- [Two level model (MO/Math.SE) vs one level model (SO)](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/612/) (Area 51)

We hope to have warm, and fruitful, relations on the line physics.SE/TP.SE. Participation in both sites is encouraged.

BTW: Don't forget to spread the word amount your coworkers and collaborators!